# How to manage a Session as a unit-of-work in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, unit-of-work

After a few years using NHibernate in Winforms and WPF, I still seem to have missed one very important point, which became too obvious when I ran this code snippet:

```
 ISessionFactory sf = Fluently.Configure()
                              .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                                .ConnectionString(c => c.Is(connectionString)))
                              .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings
                                .AddFromAssemblyOf<MyClass>())
                              .BuildSessionFactory();

 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 {
     new Task(()=>
     {
         Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}",
           i, 
           sf.OpenSession().QueryOver<MyClass>().List().Count);
     }).Start();
 }
```

This causes a lot of load, I surmise.

Honestly, the only thing I remember having read about Session handling is: Implement Unit Of Work, which proclaims atomar sessions. So, [taking a look at the pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html), I have a few concerns/questions.

- How does lazy loading fit in the picture? If I load my Data using one session, and then close it, lazy loading won't work. So, basically, the unit of work can not close / dispose the Session, meaning it is infinitely large.
- Sessions have features like `IsDirty`. If loading and saving objects is done by separate sessions, how can this still be utilized?

**EDIT:** Oren Eini has stated the very same thing as being a problem in an early [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx) of his. There, he says MicroManaging (=> use and immediate `Dispose`) cuts off NH functionality like LazyLoading and ChangeTracking. It seems to me though, that UnitOfWork is a Session MicroManagement pattern. So, what's the cleanest solution? Tracking changes myself and using MicroManagement? Monolithic sessions (= Memleak by design)? What if, unlike the example by Oren, you don't have many subdialogs that can restrict session lifetime?

Comment: The unit of work is not infinitely large, so is not the session (the session *is* the unit of work). The unit of work is atomar, does something that belongs together, and during the unit you make use of lazy loading. What is your code supposed to do? There is no unit of work, because there is no work at all, just a query.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger I'm talking about UI related issues. In many cases (Master Detail Views), you bind trunk data to a list control and, when the user selects an item, lazy load and bind the results of that to a child view. This can happen hours after the initial load.

Comment: this is something I would avoid. Binding the UI to entities is asking for troubles. It doesn't allow any business logic layers. You can't tell when a unit of work starts and ends. When you bind transactions to the UI, you get huge locking problems in the DB. You also get problems to make it all work properly with NH proxies and databinding etc.

Comment: Except for "You can't tell when a unit of work starts and ends", I could not agree less. Actually, this is how the MVVM Pattern works. It doesn't even matter if you bind the models themselves to the UI or keep them in some repository that references them (and uses lazy loading) to produce other entities for binding in the UI - the session would have to be open for a very long time, which brings me back to my original question. Can MVVM / Lazy Loading and Unit of work be unified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does lazy loading fit in the picture?

Lazy loading fits in the picture of one session. Once an object has been loaded, lazy loading allows traversing the object's graph without needing to know if an object property has already been loaded from the db, and without eagerly loading all the object graph.

Seems perfect, but there are issues though, like "n+1 select"

> If I load my Data using one session, and then close it, lazy loading won't work.

Another session, loading the same object from db, will not benefit from the properties lazy loaded in the previous session.

> So, basically, the unit of work can not close / dispose the Session, 
>   meaning it is infinitely large.

I am not sure I understand this. I guess Session is the Unit of Work.

> Sessions have features like IsDirty. 
>   If loading and saving objects is done by separate sessions, how can this still be utilized?

Loading and saving should not be done in separate sessions. I guess it is the point of the IsDirty property.

This might give you many hints on NH handling : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/100534

Hope this will help

Edit : about your second question. A usual web scenario would be like :

1. open a NH session
2. load a NH entity
3. transfer the NH entity properties in a POCO for display in the UI (keep track of Id, of course)
4. close the NH session
5. later on (user has made some changes and hits "Save" Button), open the NH session
6. load the corresponding NH entity (by its Id)
7. update the NH entity according to the new POCO fields
8. persist changes in the DB
9. close the NH Session

1,2 and 4 are parts of a first unit of work. 5,6,7,8 and 9 are parts of a second unit of work.

Comment: thanks for the response. I generally understand the principle of Lazy Loading, please see the second comment of the question, i explained what I meant. So, basically, you say one should load and save using the same session? I did that a lot, but if I understand that correctly that a bit contrary to the unit of work pattern, isn't it?

Comment: @SebastianEdelmeier added a usual scenario about the load and save. Hope this will help

Comment: thanks for the example. It actually depicts my problem. Lazy loading means : Query data when it's required. As mentioned above, in a UI that be an indistinct amount of time later than the original Query. Which is why I meant the Unit of work grows to an infinite / indeterminable size with lazy loading enabled. But your sample has another gotcha that I did not utilize so far (please correct me if I'm wrong): You recycle your reading session for saving and close it in the meantime...What's the difference between this and opening a new one and disposing the old?

Comment: "What's the difference between this and opening a new one and disposing the old?" I keep all context infos (cache, other previously loaded objects). I am able to stay in the same transaction scope. I don't have to entirely build my object, with maybe obsolete data andwith possible errors, before merging it in the session.

Comment: thanks! that sounds like a good reason...So the optimum way would be something like `use -> close -> reopen - >reuse -> ...` as you proposed, right?

Comment: Tried to find it in the API docs...how, actually can you reopen a Session that's been closed?

Comment: @SebastianEdelmeier AFAIK you can not reopen a closed session. Optimum way is to stay with the same open session just as long as the unit of work requires it. It means you have all necessary info to perform the UoW. Waiting for user input should not be part of the unit of work.

Comment: OK, thanks for your input. that means I close my session after reading and open another for saving. Which renders IsDirty useless...This is somewhat...unsatisfying, isn't it?

Comment: check this github repository: https://github.com/wbaldanw/hibernatingrhinos/tree/master/UnitOfWork     i am using it successfully now.